# Error: no mixin named breakpoint in BigCommerce custom.scss file

Tags: javascript, sass, breakpoints, bigcommerce, scss-mixins

So I'm using BigCommerce's StencilCLI and I randomly started to get a error popping up pointing to my custom sass file. It's pointing to the following code:

```
.container {
    @include breakpoint("medium") {
        max-width:106rem;
    }
    @include breakpoint("large") {
        padding: 0 3rem;
    }
}
```

which gives me the following error when I push it to github,

```
Validating theme...
/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/12.22.12/x64/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/lib/bundle-validator.js:429
                throw new Error(
                      ^

Error: no mixin named breakpoint

       Backtrace:
        stdin:25
        on line 25 of stdin
>>     @include breakpoint("medium") {
   -------------^
:  while compiling css files from "/home/runner/work/maz/maz/assets/scss/_custom.scss".
    at BundleValidator._validateCssFiles (/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/12.22.12/x64/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/lib/bundle-validator.js:429:23)
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I've read plenty of things when researching this error code about importing the mixin, but i'm not sure where to put it, or why I need to do that or if it is already done. It didn't always throw this error and plenty of other scss files use the same @include breakpoint("large/medium/small") code in their files but none of them throw the error at all.

The closest file I can find that looks like it import the breakpoint mixin is this javascript file:

```
const breakpointSizes = {
    large: 1261,
    medium: 876,
    small: 551,
};
```

Any help with an explanation of what I need to do would be helpful, the more descriptive the better.

Answer (score 0):

**New to Bigcommerce, Here is my findings**

The `breakpoint` mixin is declared in the following file: `cornerstone/node_modules/@bigcommerce/citadel/dist/tools/_toolkit.scss`

and the default break point values are declared in: `cornerstone/node_modules/@bigcommerce/citadel/dist/settings/global/screensizes/_screensizes.scss`.

if you want to override the default values you can use the below files

```
cornerstone/assets/js/theme/common/media-query-list.js
cornerstone/assets/scss/settings/global/screensizes/_screensizes.scss
```

It seems to be your `_cusotm.scss` file have no access to the breakpoint mixin, so it throws error in your custom file but not from the default files.

Where/How did you include the `custom.scss` file?

try to import `custom.scss` in `cornerstone/assets/scss/theme.scss`